# Vue.js v-for loop in laravel blade template

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-blade

I'm unable to bind index and values when using `v-for`... however when I echo array it works...

blade file content:

```
<tr class="single-member" v-for='(member, index) in members' :index='index' >
        @{{ index }}
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="First name*" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Last name*" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="Email*" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input" type="number" placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
        </div>
    </tr>
```

so this `index` is unable to get parsed and my members object is empty with fields `"name, surname, email, phone"`

NOTE that if I use `@{{ members }}` it will work, but when I want to use  `@{{ member }}` or  `@{{ index }}` that will not work, any ideas why is this happening?

an error that I'm getting is:

> app.js:6103 [Vue warn]: Property or method "index" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
> reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> (found in Root)

data object
app.js file

```
data: function() {
    return {
        gdprChecked: false,
        level: 'beginner',
        teamName: '',
        members: [],
        formError: false,
        formErrorMessage: '',
        formSuccess: false,
        formSuccessMessage: '',
    }
},
mounted() {
    // must be minimum 1 user
    this.members.push({firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', phone: ''});
},
```

working CODE, only blade file changed to this

```
<div class="columns" v-for="(member, index) in members">
    <div class="column is-narrow">
        @{{ index + 1 }}
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="{{trans('hackathon.firstName')}}" v-model="member.firstName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="{{trans('hackathon.email')}}"  v-model="member.email">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="{{trans('hackathon.lastName')}}"  v-model="member.lastName">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="{{trans('hackathon.phone')}}"  v-model="member.phone">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

still not sure why #1 not working and #2 does... any ideas?

Comment: please provide your data object ?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim added

Answer (score 0):

Try
`<tr class="single-member" v-for='member in members' :key='member.id' >`

this will refer to member.id
remember members will have to be an array of member

[vue-list key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)

Comment: I don't have an ID, and it's my bad it should go index not key... will edit it now

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this. it's worked for me

```
<tr v-for="(item,item_index) in purchase_items" :key="item_index">
   td>@{{ item_index+1 }}</td>
      <td>@{{ itemProduct(item.product_id) }}</td>
      td>@{{ itemUnit(item.unit_id) }}</td>
      <td>@{{ item.price }} * @{{ item.qty }}</td>
      <td>@{{ item.amount  }} </td>
       <td>
    <button v-on:click="removeItem(`@{{ item_index }}`)" class="btn 
      btn-danger btn-sm" > <i class="fa fa-trash-alt fa-1x"></i> </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```